# herausgehen vs hinausgehen / herauskommen vs hinauskommen

Tags: meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen Sätzen:

---

- Er kommt aus dem Zimmer heraus.
- Er kommt aus dem Zimmer hinaus.

---

---

- Er geht aus dem Zimmer hinaus.
- Er geht aus dem Zimmer heraus.

---

Ich verstehe die ersten Sätze von den beiden Beispielen.

- Er kommt aus dem Zimmer heraus - bedeutet, ich bin draußen, er kommt zu mir.
- Er geht aus dem Zimmer hinaus - bedeutet, ich bin drinnen, er entfernt sich von mir und geht nach draußen.

Aber wie verwendet man "hinauskommen" und "herausgehen"?

Answer (score 2):

*Her-* und *hin-Adverbien* legen die Bewegungsrichtung im Bezug auf den Sprecher fest. Meistens stimmt dies mit der Bewegungsrichtung im Bezug auf das im Satz genannte Objekt überein:

> Er kommt aus dem Zimmer heraus.

Jemand verlässt das Zimmer in Richtung der Sprecherin. → Die Sprecherin ist außerhalb des Zimmers.

> Er geht aus dem Zimmer hinaus.

Jemand verlässt das Zimmer weg von der Sprecherin. → Die Sprecherin ist im Zimmer.

---

Die nächste von dir genannte Beispiel ist nicht so eindeutig:

> Er geht aus dem Zimmer heraus.

Hier befindet sich die Sprecherin wie im Fall des *Kommens* außerhalb des Zimmers. Sie verwendet jedoch nicht das Verb *kommen*. Dafür kann es verschiedene Gründe geben, der naheliegendste ist, dass sie über das Verb die Art der Fortbewegung näher beschreiben will:

> Der Vogel fliegt durch das Fenster (he)raus. Der Alte hinkt die Treppe hinab. Der Karton fällt die Treppe hinunter. Der Wanderer steigt vom Gipfel herab.

Für diese Fälle sind die *hin-* und *her-Adverbien* eigentlich gedacht.

---

Es bleibt dein letztes Beispiel:

> Er kommt aus dem Zimmer hinaus.

Hier passt nichts zusammen und die meisten Deutschsprecher würden das auch nicht so sagen.

Answer (score 1):

"kommen" and "her-" express the same thing: that the movement proceeds in the direction towards the speaker (or towards the abstract vantage point where you should imagine the omniscient narrator). Likewise, "gehen" tends to express movement away from the observer, and so does "hin-". Therefore, "hinausgehen" is a much more likely construction than "herausgehen", while "hereinkommen" is much more common than "hineinkommen".

However, the semantic force of "hin-" and "her-" has been weakening for some time, so the distinction is now not as strictly observed as it used to be, and may fade away altogether.

Comment: I also find that I can very easily say something like "Er geht zu mir", so it's not only the semantics of _hin-_ and _her-_ that aren't watertight.

Comment: As I already wrote in my own answer, unlike "kommen" (= to come), which is imperatively a movement towards the observer, "gehen" (= to go) is not so strictly related to the direction.

Answer (score 1):

*Wenn* die Leute bewusst darauf achten würden, gäbe es zumindest bezüglich eines ortsfesten Betrachters kein hin(aus)kommen, denn kommen impliziert immer eine Bewegung auf den Betrachter zu. (Beim "gehen" ist es nicht so klar definiert).
Viele Leute machen sich beim Sprechen aber überhaupt keine Gedanken darüber (manche nichtmal beim Schreiben), ob in einer bestimmten Situation *hin*ein oder *her*ein angebracht ist.

Etwas anderes ist es, wenn der Sprecher selbst sich bewegt, dann kann er sich durchaus fragen "wie komme ich hinein/hinaus?" - einschließlich der Phrase (meist in empörten Tonfall), mit der ein inakzeptabler Vorschlag abgelehnt wird: "wo kommen wir denn da hin!"

Comment: Aber in "wo kommen wir denn da hin" ist _hin_ ja die zweite Hälfte von _wohin_, nicht kurz für _hinaus_. Und der Unterschied zwischen _wohin_ und _woher_ ist ein viel stärkerer als der zwischen _hinaus_ und _heraus_. (Ich habe noch nie jemanden _wohin_ und _woher_ verwechseln hören.)

Comment: Es ging mir dabei um die Kombination von "hin" und "kommen", und die ist auch gegeben, wenn das "hin" ein Bestandteil von "wohin" ist. Um den Gegensatz zwischen "hin" und "her" ging es in besagtem Beispiel nicht.

Answer (score 0):

In spoken German make it simple. No "hinaus" oder "heraus", just say "raus". "Er ist aus dem Zimmer raus gegangen."

Answer (score 0):

english below
Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch werden die Wörter hinaus und heraus oft synonym verwendet. Dies entsteht insbesondere durch regionale Unterschiede der Wortverwendung. Betrachtet man es sehr genau kann 'hinaus gehen' oder 'heraus kommen'.
Man kann jedoch auch 'aus sich heraus gehen'. Dies ist eine Redewendung und bedeutet soviel wie, jemand tut oder sagt etwas, was deutlich besser ist, als das typische Verhalten.
english
These words are used synonym in the daily language. Depending on the region the one or the other word is used more.
Being precise, there is either 'hinaus gehen' or 'heraus kommen'. There is in German no rule without exception(s). There is a idiom which says 'aus sich heraus gehen'. This means, someone exceeds its typical behavior.

Comment: Das beantwortet die Frage nicht.